# Why setPivotX() just replace views?

Tags: android, animation

In code - after first part of animation pivot of view is changing and...view position too!(it is strange behavior)

Here's code(stipulation - one ValueAnimator):

```
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0,180);


float firstAnimLineX = ((47.5f * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density));
float firstAnimLineY = ((2.5f * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density));
float secondAnimLineX = ((47.5f * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density));
float secondAnimLineY = ((47.5f * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density));

animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
    view.setPivotX((Float) animator.getAnimatedValue()>180/2?firstAnimLineX : secondAnimLineX);
    view.setPivotY((Float) animator.getAnimatedValue()>180/2?firstAnimLineY : secondAnimLineY);

    view.setRotation((Float) animator.getAnimatedValue());

    }
});
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/line"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is what i want to do(left part; right part - it's what realy happens)(yellow point - pivot):[image]
I watched source code of setPivotX but it doesn't says me anything.
Maybe i should call someone of invalidate-methods of view?

Comment: firstAnimLineX = secondAnimLineX in your code. Is this intentional or by mistake?

Comment: @0X0nosugar i can do it as a one variable, but is for more informatible view of code and it's for example, in real project i use different values. But problem the same, i want to find source of problem - why view replaces  and how to make correct animation

Comment: Well, I set up a small sample and tried to reproduce your problem but my TextView flipped over and vanished behind the ActionBar :( I suppose it's because I'm using a different layout and maybe a different emulator. Maybe you could share enough code/ xml so that we are talking about the same thing?

Comment: @0X0nosugar ,you doesn't forgot about my problem,thank you! I added my XML, but i think it's just strange behavior of setPivot...or,less likely, ValueAnimator.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated this code and ran it on my Android phone. It gives the exact animation you are looking for.

I created an Image to match your 'match-stick' image.
I made it 400 px wide by 40 high for an example.

I gave it the id: 'bar'

```
ImageView bar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bar = findViewById(R.id.bar);
    bar.getLayoutParams().width = 400; // I set the dimensions here.
    bar.getLayoutParams().height = 40; // I set the dimensions here.
    bar.setX(0); bar.setY(0); // Then I positioned it in upper left corner.

    bar.setPivotX(380); // I set the pivot a little inside the image so that it looks kinda like it is pivoting on a nail.
    bar.setPivotY(20);
    bar.animate().rotation(-90).setDuration(2000); // Here it animates from your first image above, to your second image in 2 seconds.

// Here I used a postDelay to allow the first animation to finish its' 2 seconds 'before' calling the second animation. No need for an animate() - listener now.

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            bar.setY(360); // This re-positions the original image to the 
                           // location where the animation ended.
            bar.setRotation(90); // Because the original image was horizontal, this turns it vertical.

// Now we finish the animation to your 3rd image above.

            bar.animate().rotation(0).setDuration(2000);
        }
    },2100);


}
```

Comment: I think i should use setX() or setTranslateX(), I thought about hard setting position, but it adds even more questions: wouldn't it be too hard for UpdateListener? - an every animating itteration sets new position(because i wont make two,sequentially playing, ValueAnimators)(in real project i will have to create more than ten animators) and second question is the same - why view repaces? Its just setting pivot, not margins, view size or something,that makes view tranforms in any dimension

Comment: According to your diagram above, it appears to me that your  2nd animation is from Image-State-1 to Image-State-3. That is why the image is off-screen. After the first animate, you should update the Images intended new coordinates, so that the second animation works correctly. Animate... redefine the new location... then animate.

Comment: animate->redefine->animate -treatment is not good in this case,because it will be a non-optimized call of redefine method if i will use only one Animator. If i use 2 Animators in this code(example code), in real project it will be too much Animators. Fot coordinates - i change pivot coorginates in UpdateListener,but if i not change view coordinates - i think i should oriented by view's original state coordinates(is should be 47.5x 2.5y for second tact of animation),and if view didn't replaces, it was successful, but..

Comment: i can forcebly translate by x/y inside updateListener,but it will be a crutch

Comment: and! important thing,that i already do reposition of view by setRotation-method, it's not relates to animation, its relates to views presentation, so...i don't know how to do re-position

Comment: I replaced my previous comments above with a small program I wrote to create what you are looking for. I ran it on my Android and it works smoothly.

Comment: On a side note: I'm not sure what your animation is for, but perhaps with this method, you can adapt it for your needs. Hope it helps.